# How to implement the idea inside Style?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, .net-4.5

The idea:

There is grid inside Window. I need to create Style for 2 scenarios.

Scenario 1:

1. Mouse enters grid.
2. Mouse leaves grid
3. Grid's background becomes Red.

Scenario 2:

1. Mouse enters grid.
2. Mouse presses on grid.
3. Mouse leaves grid.
4. Grid's background becomes blue.

Shortly: If mouse presses - make it blue, if not - make it red.

I tried, but to set Binding or DynamicResource on freezable objects like Storyboard inside Style is impossible.

XAML:

```
    <Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="GridStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type Grid}">
        <Style.Resources>
            <Storyboard x:Key="OnMouseLeave1">
                <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="{x:Null}">
                    <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="Red"/>
                </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
        </Style.Resources>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="UIElement.MouseLeave">
                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource  OnMouseLeave1}"/>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"/>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid x:Name="grid" Style="{DynamicResource GridStyle1}" Background="White"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use Windows Forms in an Android app.  That doc is misleading - it is showing you everything in the BCL, not the classes specifically supported in Xamarin Android.